# Binding C-; in Emacs as a prefix key

Tags: emacs, terminal, key-bindings

I'd like <kbd>C-;</kbd> to behave as if I pressed <kbd>ESC</kbd> or <kbd>C-[</kbd>.

I tried `(global-set-key (kbd "C-;") esc-map)` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Your question

The following works for me:

```
(define-key global-map (kbd "C-;") esc-map)
```

Now, <kbd>C-h c C-; q</kbd> reports `C-; q runs the command fill-paragraph`.

Note that [`global-set-key`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Binding-Commands.html) is an interactive command, [`define-key`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Changing-Key-Bindings.html) is more appropriate for `.emacs` (although both should work).

## Your problem

You are running on a terminal (as opposed to a GUI) and <kbd>C-;</kbd> is seen by Emacs as <kbd>;</kbd> (use <kbd>C-h c C-;</kbd> to verify).

You need to either

- use GUI,
- use a different key, or
- configure your terminal to pass <kbd>C-;</kbd> to its subprocesses.

Another possible source of problems might stem from things like [Translation Keymaps](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Translation-Keymaps.html).

Comment: I tried that, but C-; is the same as ; which still results in a call to self-insert-command. I do see the change in the global map under the key 67108923 however.

Comment: @dan You're probably using Emacs in a terminal.  Most terminals are limited in the keys they can recognize compared to a GUI environment.  Either pick a different key, use a GUI version of Emacs, or figure out how to configure your terminal to recognize the key (which may not be possible).

Comment: Also, `global-set-key` is just a thin wrapper around `define-key` (look at the source with `M-x find-function RET global-set-key`).  I've never had trouble with using `global-set-key` in my init.el, and if it doesn't work with `global-set-key`, it probably won't with `define-key`.

Comment: @jpkotta Indeed I am using iTerm2. In the Preferences pane for Keys I was able to remap C-; to output an escape key (hex code 0x1b).

Comment: @dan: please check out Translation-Keymaps (see edit)